# Is there such a thing as unsteamed rolled oats?

Tags: raw, oats

Is there such a thing as truly raw (unsteamed) rolled oats? Why are rolled oats usually lightly steamed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rolled uncooked **groats** will shatter. You can get uncooked, unrolled oats though. Food coops and organic grocery stores/coops have them. $1.49 a pound is a good price. You want **hulled oat groats**, as it takes considerable technology to get the hulls off. Sold in bulk, or one pound bags. You can get 50Lb bags online. They'll last a year or more.It takes about 2 hours to cook them in a rice cooker. Brown rice 2X. Add just enough water to cover on the second cycle. Let them sit on warm fir half an hour to reduce stickiness. Chicken broth and brown sesame seed oil are good additives. Dirty oats, Mexican style, or Stroganoff style, with sour cream, mushrooms and onions added at end are both pretty tasty. Of course, you can eat them plain too.

Comment: What about rolled soaked groats?

Comment: Never tried them. As seeds, they take a 5 hour soak to get them to germinate at a reasonable rate. 24 hours is too long, and they still feel hard and crunchy. You *might* get away with boiling for an hour. That'll soften things, but I'm not sure enough to roll them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're called unstabilized oats, and they can go rancid, so must be refrigerated.