# Who sells unstabilized (truly raw) oats in the U.S.?

Tags: shopping, raw, united-states

Who sells [unstabilized (unsteamed, truly raw) oats](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/97226/42013) in the U.S.?

Comment: I've voted to close this because "shopping" questions are difficult to answer, due to many possible answers and suppliers may change over time.

Comment: As the grain is effectively a seed ... I'd say look at [Southern States](https://www.southernstates.com/catalog/product/p-10073-imperial-whitetail-oats-plus-45-lb), [Tractor Supply](https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/evolved-harvest-throw-gro-x-treme-oats) or other farm-supply stores.

Comment: @Erica By definition, unstabilized oats are rolled but not steamed.

Comment: @Joe I think you're on the right track. And I'm not sure, if found, they would be for human consumption.

Comment: @Erica : the question wasn't about rolled oats.  My understanding is that rolled oats would *always* be steamed first.  The linked question has a follow-up comment asking about rolled unsteamed groats, but that wasn't part of the question here.  (also possibly worth mentioning -- oats sold for seed likely have the hull still on, whereas buying 'groats' would have it removed)

Comment: The content of the linked question when this one was asked had an answer (by this OP) indicating that unstabilized oats were unsteamed rolled oats. That has changed over time :) so I'll withdraw my previous comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oats from Tractor supply are definitely uncooked (about $15 for 50 Lb). I've planted them to grow cat grass for years. Unfortunately, they are also not hulled. Hulling is usually done by hurling the oats at a steel wall at about 70mph, then separating oat from empty hull and oats still with hull by fractionating through a stream of air. Naturally, buoyancy depends on a groat's size, as well as its density. It's a tricky task to run at home. You can make a centrifuge out of an old angle grinder, with an impeller designed to get the oats up to speed, but the air driven density separation is quite hard to mimic with only an 8 foot ceiling. There are other ways the separation can be accomplished, but dry oats tend to build up quite a static charge when you roll them around.
For whole, uncooked, dehulled oat groats you'll want either a food coop or a health food store. At about $1.50 a pound you can usually do as well or better than the 50Lb sacks available through Amazon.